# HIde and Show a simple text in javascript during site load

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, settimeout, show

I want to hide a some words from a phrase and show only the specific word.

for exemple:
HTML:

```
<h1> hello <span class="w1 hidden"> My </span><span class="w2 hidden"> Name</span><span class="w3 hidden"> Is </span><br> Jonh</h1>
```

Javascript:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".w1").removeClass("hidden").addClass("animated flipInX");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(".w1").removeClass("animated flipInX").addClass("hidden");
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(".w2").removeClass("hidden").addClass("animated flipInX");
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(".w2").removeClass("animated flipInX").addClass("hidden");
    }, 8000);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(".w3").removeClass("hidden").addClass("animated flipInX");
    }, 8000);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(".w3").removeClass("animated flipInX").addClass("hidden");
    }, 12000);
```

All the words at the bigining are hiddem.
the w1 word (My) load after 2 seconds. and after more 2 seconds i hide this word, and at the same time i hide the w1 word i show the w2 word( Name), and after for 4 sec i hide w2 and show w3 and hide after more 4 seconds.

now i need to restart the porcess and at 12 sec, and load again the w1 word, and after the w2 and w3 and return again to w1 word.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?  Also, do you require support for <IE10?  If not, animation keyframes might give you a lot more flexibility and ease-of-use.  Here's a tutorial that I found helpful: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Answer (score 1):

just do the same and use addClass() ? but You Also have the function .hide() and you can use .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() take a look on the jQuery documentation for more example

Comment: but I do not want to repeat code. I want the process to occur while the page is loaded in the browser. page 10 if you have a min of thousands of lines of code. I want it to be dynamic.

i want make the time a variable and incraise 5 seconds to occur every cycle, and repeats forever

Answer (score 0):

You want to do fadeIn() fadeOut() of your text every 5seconds for example ?

something like this ?

```
<h1> hello <span class="hidden"> My </span><span class="w2 hidden"> Name</span><span class="hidden"> Is </span><br> Jonh</h1>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    while(i < 100){
        $('.hidden').fadeOut();
        $('.hidden').fadeIn();
        i++;
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zQrM5/1/

Comment: yes, but one word at a time. frist i only show my, and words name is, are hiden, after 5 seconds i see name, and My & is are hidden